# Generate thumbnail from image buffer on front end in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, buffer, thumbnails

I have created a server that reads image files and sends the image as a buffer to the client which displays it using some HTML5 src magic. But I wish to create a thumbnail for the image so that I can use it as a gallery. Are there any good libraries that can use an image buffer and create a small, possibly 64x64 thumbnail?

Thanks.